# Load more posts with Ajax and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to scroll down to load more posts instead of loading all posts in the first time.

The one way that I know is using ajax(getpost) and JS(check scroll down)

When JS scrolling down event occurs,use JS to append a new post with html code

so for the append content, I am using '/' at the end of each line and put new element with '"+XXX+"' and need to change " to "

but I think it is not very efficient way for me to change post html code

Is there any other way to do this function instead of every time append a whole bunch of code? since one post may more than 100 lines of code, so it is too inconvenient.

```
    append("<div class='post'>\
    <h2>"+title+"</h2>\
    <p>"+description+"</p>\
    .....\
    </div>");
```

Comment: You can use this plugin: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: Plugins will not do any magic than `append`

Comment: "so for the append content, I am using '/' at the end of each line and put new element with '"+XXX+"' and need to change 'to' ". Please explain this line well as it is not understandable

Comment: check this link: http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/JGQPPa

Comment: Check this : http://phppot.com/jquery/load-data-dynamically-on-page-scroll-using-jquery-ajax-and-php/

Comment: are you returning html or Json from server ?  if its html then use a parent container and append received data to it. If its json then  loop it, generate each row data as HTML and append it to the parent container.

Comment: @abhirathore2006 but how can avoid other people to use the same url to get json for themselves? since the url is in js and public